# IOS launch images - driving me crazy

Tags: ios, xcode

Apple does not provide a clear list for image file size I should use for:

- retina hd 5.5 portrait ios 8,9
- retinia hd 5.5 portrait ios 8,9
- retinia hd 5.5 landscape ios 8,9
- iphone portrait ios 2x 7-9
- iphone portrait ios retina 4 7-9
- ipad portrait ios 1x 7-9
- ipad portrait ios 2x 7-9
- ipad landscape ios 1x 7-9
- ipad landscape ios 2x 7-9
- etc.

As I intend to use swift I can only suppose ios7+ that means I can ignore all he other sizes for ios5+6. Is that correct?

(One could also go LaunchScreen.storyboard solution, but that has higher iOS requirements so for now it seems better to include launch images.)

How to solve the issue of creating all launch images in correct dimensions?

**Note to those who put this question on hold:**
I originally asked if anyone knew of a list with specifications. Apparently that was why you closed the answer 3 years later after I posted it. But in essence this question is and was a programming question regarding Apple API specifications with precise answers possible. It is **not** a question seeking opinion based answers.

Comment: Remember that the launch screen storyboard will only be used with iOS 8.0 and later. If you wish to support earlier versions of iOS, you must also include launch images for your supported devices.

Comment: Apple usually supplies this information in their documentation. Check their [human/user interface guide](https://www.google.com/search?q=apple+human+user+interface+guide).

Comment: The people who closed this question citing "recommend to find a book..."  The question is a programming question regarding Apple API specifications with precise answers possible. It is NOT a question seeking opinion based answers...

Comment: I've been coding for the iOS platform for a decade and Apple has never, to my recollection, published a simple but critical guideline that enables developers to match a device, operating system, and pixel size for screen, launch images and app icons. This is baffling and honestly, a waste of time for developers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use a LaunchImage set. Click Images.xcassets from the files list. In the next column to the right, you may need to use the "+" button to add AppIcon and LaunchImages image sets. These will have slots for every supported (expected) screen size. If you use these sets, you don't have to worry about encrypting your image files with Apple's indecipherable naming scheme, you just drag each image file to the corresponding slot in the set.

Of course, one still has to know the actual dimensions associated with 1x, 2x, retina4, Retina 4.7, Retina 5.5, etc. I'd certainly prefer Xcode to just show the required dimensions of each image, but it doesn't. Barring that, I'd love a single table from Apple listing all the expected dimensions, <s>but that doesn't seem to exist, either</s>. It looks like Apple has, thankfully, consolidated all of this information in the https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/ under the "Graphics" section. Specifically, as of this writing for devices supported on IOS10:

```
Device                          Portrait size       Landscape size
iPhone 6s Plus, iPhone 6 Plus   1080px by 1920px    1920px by 1080px
iPhone 6s, iPhone 6             750px by 1334px     1334px by 750px
iPhone SE                       640px by 1136px     1136px by 640px
12.9-inch iPad Pro              2048px by 2732px    2732px by 2048px
9.7-inch iPad Pro, iPad Air 2, 
     iPad mini 4, iPad mini 2   1536px by 2048px    2048px by 1536px
```

Comment: First link is dead now...

Comment: 2nd link is gone too.

Comment: Updated link: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/

Answer (score 161):

For anyone finding this now i've created a list to simply explain what each of Apple's somewhat confusing names actually mean.

---

#### iPhone Portrait iOS 8,9

- Retina HD 5.5 *(iPhone 6 Plus)* - 1242px x 2208px - Default-736h@3x.png
- Retina HD 4.7 *(iPhone 6)* - 750px x 1334px - Default-667h@2x.png

---

#### iPhone Landscape iOS 8,9

- Retina HD 5.5 *(iPhone 6 Plus)* - 2208px x 1242px - Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png

---

#### iPhone Portrait iOS 7-9

- 2x *(iPhone 4)* - 640px x 960px - Default@2x.png
- Retina 4 *(iPhone 5)* - 640px x 1136px - Default-568h@2x.png

---

#### iPhone Portrait iOS 5,6

- 1x *(iPhone 3)* - 320px x 480px - Default.png
- 2x *(iPhone 4)* - 640px x 960px - Default@2x.png
- Retina 4 *(iPhone 5)* - 640px x 1136px - Default-568h@2x.png

Comment: It would be nice to know where you got this information from...

Comment: where is the landscape for iPhone 6 / Retina HD 4.7" ?

Comment: @Mike - You can find the image names by adding images to the LaunchImage asset and then archiving and exporting the app for Adhoc deployment. Then change the exported app's extension from '.ipa' to '.zip'. Open the .zip to see the app payload, then right-click and choose 'Show Package Contents'. Then you'll be able to see all the launch image files and their files names given by Apple.

Comment: @NikkyD - At the moment there is no launch image for the iPhone 6 / Retina HD 4.7" via the asset catalog.

Comment: @Simo thank you. It helps. Can you also share the ipad screen with resolutions please

Comment: What about iPhone 7, +? it doesn't use HD 4.7 HD5.5 images..just a blank screen. What I did wrong?

Comment: @Simo iPhone X?

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard  * iPhone X Portrait iOS 11+
    * Portrait - 1125px × 2436px
    * Landscape - 2436px × 1125px

Comment: if not using assets images.xcassette, the file name for portrait iPhone X is Default-1218h@2x.png for landscape Default-Landscape-1218h@2x.png

Comment: @Simo, is it ok to have just one launch image say LaunchImage@3x.png in your project, will apple reject my app because of not providing other configuration images, the reason why I wanna do is because my image is of around 25 KB.

Comment: how to use that Launch image set on splash screen?

Answer (score 39):

New Dimensions table for Xcode Version 9.0

---

### iPhone X Portrait iOS 11+

iPhone X : 1125x2436px

### iPhone X Landscape iOS 11+

iPhone X : 2436x1125px

---

### iPhone Portrait iOS 8.9

Retina HD 5.5 : 1242x2208px
Retina HD 4.7 : 750x1334px

### iPhone Landscape iOS 8.9

Retina HD 5.5 : 2208x1242px

---

### iPhone Portrait 7-9

2x : 640x960px
Retina 4 : 640x1136px

---

### iPad Portrait 7-9

1x ; 768x1024px
2x : 1536x2048px

### iPad Landscape iOS 7-9

1x : 1024x768px
2x : 2048x1536px

---

### iPhone Portrait 5,6

1x : 320x480px
2x : 640x960
Retina 4  : 640x1136px

---

### iPad Portrait Without Status Bar iOS 5,6

1x : 768x1004px
2x : 1536x2008px

### iPad Portrait 5,6

1x : 768x1024px
2x : 1536x2048px

---

### iPad Landscape Without Status Bar iOS 5,6

1x : 1024x748px
2x : 2048x1496px

### iPad Landscape 5,6

1x : 1024x768px
2x : 2048x1536px

Comment: maybe you meen iPad instead of iPhone for "iPhone Portrait 7-9" and "iPhone Ladscape iOS 7-9". Thx any... you saved my day!

Comment: Retina HD 4.7  landscape no option? it is always picking portrait even in landscape

Answer (score 12):

Although not pretty I use this quick way

```
1. Create a new LaunchImage and drop any file onto each box
2. Build it , it will fail or have some warnings
3. Click on the "Show Report navigator" and you'll see the sizes/names for each
4. On your image editor resize the image to the proper sizes/names and overwrite to
the respective file as reported in 3. each file is on 
<proj dir>/Assets.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchImage
```

Do the same for icons and don't look back

Answer (score 6):

As with the other answers I use an Asset Catalog and simply drop files into the LaunchImage slots in the Asset Catalog in Xcode.  Then I find my app in the Products Group of the Xcode Navigator (tall pane on the left) and Show in Finder.  Any copy of your app package will do.  Then I Show Package Contents on my app and all the LaunchImage*.png files are there.  I just added a portrait launch image for the iPhone X.  To see the names and sizes of the immages I navigated to the package in Terminal and ran the file command on the LaunchImage*.png files.

```
% file LaunchImage*.png
LaunchImage-1100-2436h@3x.png:         PNG image data, 1125 x 2436, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
LaunchImage-700-568h@2x.png:           PNG image data, 640 x 1136, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
LaunchImage-700-Landscape@2x~ipad.png: PNG image data, 2048 x 1536, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
LaunchImage-700-Landscape~ipad.png:    PNG image data, 1024 x 768, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
LaunchImage-700-Portrait@2x~ipad.png:  PNG image data, 1536 x 2048, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad.png:     PNG image data, 768 x 1024, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
LaunchImage-700@2x.png:                PNG image data, 640 x 960, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
LaunchImage-800-667h@2x.png:           PNG image data, 750 x 1334, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
LaunchImage-800-Portrait-736h@3x.png:  PNG image data, 1242 x 2208, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

Comment: Now this is interesting. For me, the LaunchImage-1100-2436h@3x.png is the landscape one, and the Portrait one does not seem to be copied over to the product, although portrait orientation is enabled. Do you have any sources for the resulting iPhone X launch-screen names of the product?

Comment: My app only supports Portrait.  So I didn't have Landscape checked.  Once I did and also supplied both a Portrait and Landscape image, only the Landscape image was copied.  Sigh.

Comment: Busted. Would you mind duplicating my radar? Unbelievable Apple went GM with that.

Comment: Where are the iPad Pro LaunchImages? (2048x2732 & 2732x2048)

Comment: For me the iPhone X splash screen is called: `LaunchImage-1100-Portrait-2436h`

Answer (score 4):

I was dealing with a similar issue to adapt to new iPhone X new screen size and came across [this link](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/)

It helped me, maybe it will help someone else

[image]

Comment: Is it ok to have just one launch image say LaunchImage@3x.png in your project, will apple reject my app because of not providing other configuration images, the reason why I wanna do is because my image is of around 25 KB.

Answer (score 2):

It's so confusing.  Can anyone align the sizes along with the names.  Is there a link.

So far I have only this from the other list that seems at all helpful.

The dimensions themselves are helpful only 1/2 way.  We need to be able to associate it to the referencing png.

Here's what I have so far, but it's far from complete.  Is there a complete list:

```
iPhone Portrait iOS 8,9
Retina HD 5.5 (iPhone 6 Plus) - 1242px x 2208px - Default-736h@3x.png
Retina HD 4.7 (iPhone 6) - 750px x 1334px - Default-667h@2x.png
iPhone Landscape iOS 8,9
Retina HD 5.5 (iPhone 6 Plus) - 2208px x 1242px - Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png
iPhone Portrait iOS 7-9
2x (iPhone 4) - 640px x 960px - Default@2x.png
Retina 4 (iPhone 5) - 640px x 1136px - Default-568h@2x.png
iPhone Portrait iOS 5,6
1x (iPhone 3) - 320px x 480px - Default.png
2x (iPhone 4) - 640px x 960px - Default@2x.png
Retina 4 (iPhone 5) - 640px x 1136px - Default-568h@2x.png
```

Answer (score 0):

**Launch image for the iPhone Portrait Mode**

[image: here you can targetted your desired ios]

**iPhone X Portrait iOS 11+** (image size 1125 × 2436 pixels)

**Retina HD 5.5″** (image size 1242 × 2208 pixels)

**Retina HD 4.7″** (image size 750 × 1334 pixels)

**iPhone Portrait 2x** (image size 640 × 960 pixels)

**iPhone Retina 4** (image size 640 × 1136 pixels)

**For background images you will need 4 sizes to support the above devices in portrait orientation.  They can be stored in whatever folder in your project that you are keeping standard images in.  The sizes needed are as follows…**

•    640 x 960 (iPhone 4s)

•    640 x 1136 (iPhone 5s)

•    750 x 1334 (iPhone 6)

•    1242 x 2208 (iPhone 6 Plus)

•    1125 × 2436 (iPhone X)