# What are iOS iPad launchpad image resolutions?

Tags: ios, ipad, launchimage

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35213674/1299362) gives the image resolutions and device types for the Xcode Launchpad Image.xcassettes for iPhones. What is the corresponding information for iPads?

Comment: Don't use launch images, use a single launch screen file. This is required to support the iPad Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25759231/1299362) gives a clear concise answer for Iphone, Ipad and Apple watch.

Answer (score 3):

google is your friend. Apple has a list for all device sizes here
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/

Full table:

```
            UILaunchImages = {
            {  --iPhone 4 Portait
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "Portrait",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{320, 480}"
            },
            {  --iPhone 4 LandscapeLeft
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeLeft",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{320, 480}"
            },
            {  --iPhone 4 LandscapeRight
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeRight",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{320, 480}"
            },
            {  --iPhone 5 Portait
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-568h",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "Portrait",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{320, 568}"
            },
            {  --iPhone 5 LandscapeLeft
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-568h",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeLeft",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{320, 568}"
            },
            {  --iPhone 5  LandscapeRight
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-568h",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeRight",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{320, 568}"
            },
            { -- iPad / iPad Retina
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-Portrait",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "Portrait",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{768, 1024}" 
            }, 
            { -- iPad / iPad Retina
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-Landscape",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeLeft",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{768, 1024}" 
            },
            { -- iPad / iPad Retina
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-Landscape",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeRight",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{768, 1024}" 
            }, 
            {  --iPhone 6 Portrait
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "8.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-667h",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "Portrait",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{375, 667}"
            },
            {  --iPhone 6 LandscapeLeft
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "8.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-667h",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeLeft",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{375, 667}"
            },
            {  --iPhone 6 LandscapeRight
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "8.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-667h",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeRight",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{375, 667}"
            },
            { -- iPhone 6 Plus Portrait
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "8.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-736h",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "Portrait",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{414, 736}"
            },
            { -- iPhone 6 Plus landscape left
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "8.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-Landscape-736h",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeLeft",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{414, 736}"
            },
            { -- iPhone 6 Plus landscape right
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "8.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-Landscape-736h",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeRight",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{414, 736}"
            },
            { -- iPad Pro Portrait
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "9.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-Portrait-1336",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "Portrait",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{1024, 1366}"
            },
            { -- iPad Pro Landscape Right
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "9.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-Landscape-1336",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeRight",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{1024, 1366}"
            },
            { -- iPad Pro Landscape Left
                ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "9.0",
                ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-Landscape-1336",
                ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeLeft",
                ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{1024, 1366}"
            },
        },
```

Comment: This is useful so I upvoted it, however, I have found a more concise source, see my answer below.