# How to take Iphone 4 screenshots with Xcode 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35213674/1299362) gives the image resolutions needed for the Xcode Images.xcassettes when doing the launch image for the Iphone.  One of the images needed is the 2x for the Iphone 4. However, since upgrading to Xcode 8, the target builds are only Iphone 5 and above. How do I get a screenshot from the Iphone 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode -> Preferences -> Components

Install older version of simulator and iPhone 4S will appear in simulator list.

4 and 4S had identical screen resolutions.

P.S. You also need to set project deployment target to the older version you installed

Comment: This works well. I installed the simulator for IOS 8.1

Answer (score 0):

**Don't Take.**

In XCode 8.0, You are set deployment target `8.0+`, it means in You are developing apps for `iOS 8.0` and `later`. `iOS 8` and `later` will be compatible with iPhone 4s, iPhone 5, iPhone 5c, iPhone 5s, iPod touch 5th generation, iPad 2, iPad with Retina display, iPad Air, iPad mini, and iPad mini with Retina display. So it looks like the iPhone 4 is officially dead to Apple.

**You are take iPhone 4S screen shot. if You are set the deployment target 8.0.**

[image]