# How to set Background Image correctly

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to set a background image to my app but the image is not centered. The resolution is 640x1136, I have only one size, do I need more ? What is @2x and @3x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**
I ended up spending ~ an hour in chat with the OP, and the solution to their problem was ultimately to remove all launch screen assets from the xc bundle and instead just put a `UIImageView` on the launch screen storyboard, anchor each side of it to the sides of the view, and set fill mode to aspect fill.  That said, the below information is more likely to solve the problem for the majority of people who run into this, I think.

---

You need different sized images for the different screen sizes & aspect ratios.  From the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/):

> It’s best to use an Xcode storyboard for your launch screen, but you can provide a set of static images if necessary. Create static images in different sizes for different devices, and be sure to include the status bar region.

The documentation includes a large table with all possible screen sizes one might support.

[Many](http://matthewpalmer.net/blog/2014/09/10/iphone-6-plus-launch-image-adaptive-mode/) [tutorials](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html) [exist](https://medium.com/@jigarm/ios-app-icon-and-launch-image-sizes-e8d5990cb72b) on the topic, and they may be a good place to start.  [This similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34112681/ios-launch-images-driving-me-crazy) also has a number of useful and informative answers.

Personally, I make one high-resolution image and then drop it into a tool which automatically generates all necessary screen sizes for me.  I do the same thing for all the app icon sizes. Many such tools exist; SO is not an appropriate place to pontificate on which tools are better than others, so I will leave that choice (and research) up to you.

As far as where to **put** the images, the following instructions from [Matthew Palmer's tutorial](http://matthewpalmer.net/blog/2014/09/10/iphone-6-plus-launch-image-adaptive-mode/) should be sufficient to get you started:

> 1   In Xcode, Click on your Assets file (Images.xcassets) in the left sidebar. It should open in the main pane.
>
> 2 In the left sidebar of the main pane (where AppIcon, LaunchImage, etc. are), right click
>
> 3 Select New Launch Image
>
> 4 Add your new launch images as normal. If you want something quick and easy to use, Paul Haddad recommends taking a screenshot in the iPhone 6 simulator and using that, or DavidSmith has created some default ones.
>
> 5 Change the Launch Images Source from your Target’s settings.

I found a useful list of launch screen resolution sizes [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/creating-launch-screens-ios), which I will quote below:

> Image Resolution  Image name
>
> 320x480   Default.png
>
> 640x960   Default@2x.png
>
> 640x1136  Default-568h@2x.png
>
> 750x1334  Default-667h@2x.png
>
> 1242x2208 Default-736h@3x.png
>
> 768x1024  Default-Portrait.png
>
> 1024x768  Default-Landscape.png
>
> 1536x2048 Default-Portrait@2x.png
>
> 2048x1536 Default-Landscape@2x.png

The link where the above table was quoted from is also probably the best tutorial I was able to find on the topic.  Note that, if you make the larger sizes first and drag them into Xcode, Xcode and auto-generate many of the smaller resolutions for you.  (For example, providing one iPad resolution will typically be sufficient for all iPad resolutions.)

Comment: Thanks for reply, so I'll use Matthew Palmer's method to set my background images. There is a lots of cases but I don't see the resolutions. In addition, it seems that I have to change the images depending of the iOS version...

Comment: Happy to help!  If my answer answered your question, please mark it as correct w/ the green checkmark.  Same applies for the other answers.  Alternatively, if the solution was something else (for example, if you found the solution in a link in my answer), go ahead and write your own answer to your question and mark it as correct so others can quickly find the solution!  Thanks :)

Comment: In fact, I don't know which resolution I should have (maybe I've not understand all your post, im a 16yo French developper :P) but I don't see the resolutions to use

Comment: Gotcha!  Just edited with explicit list of resolutions.  Try just putting in the iPhone X, iPhone 8 Plus, and iPad Pro resolutions first, and I think most of the others will be auto-generated by Xcode in the `Assets.xcassets` view in Xcode.  Then whatever isn't done automatically you can go ahead and make yourself.  Hope this works!

Comment: I'll try this. So, my app is only portrait and for iPhone not iPad, so I make a 1242x2208 for iPhone 8+ and the others will be automatically generated ?

Comment: In my experience, yes, but I haven't made an iPhone app in a while.  Give it a try and take a look at that last link I provided before the table in my answer and see how it goes.

Comment: The app crashes : "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157616/discussion-between-max-von-hippel-and-erwann-bestard).

Comment: I resolved this by adding a ImageView in the storyboard, whatever the size, it works

Answer (score 1):

Ok let's take this one question at a time...

- Background Image not being centered, I assume you have an ImageView containing that image... If so you should be able to do something like `imageView.contentMode = .center`
- The @2x and @3x are for the newer phones with higher resolution. It is advised to have all 3. Also if you could show any code that would help.

Comment: I suspect OP is doing this through Xcode, in the GUI, rather than programmatically.  (But Erwann, certainly comment accordingly if I'm wrong here!)

Comment: @MaxvonHippel Good point! I assume then we have answered this question GUI or Code :P

Comment: Thanks for reply, im not using the image view but I set the background programatically in the ViewDidLoad()